# silverlight and spring.net

Tags: silverlight, spring.net

can i use both silverlight and spring.net in the same web based project

Comment: I don't see why not. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is your reason to use it for silverlight, too? I assume you want to share some configuration files, right? Otherwise you could use an other IoC-Container (like Ninject) which is more "leight-weight" if you are only interested in IoC.

Comment: It might be difficult to get it running if you plan to use silverlight for Windows Phone (Spring.net is not available for this platform).

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a client technology and spring.net is a server technology, as long as you aren't trying to implement a Silverlight client that is also a spring server, you should be able to do whatever you want with the two.

Comment: Spring.net is not a "server-side" technology. Well, it is (currently?) not compiled for client profile and some web dependent components are not meant to be used on the client side but e.g. the IoC-Container has nothing to do with client/server differenciation. But AFAIK there is no build of Spring.Core for Silverlight (leaving some components beside) so thats is the real reason why you cant use it.